# How do I convert an entire block in erb to html entities?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have something like the following:

```
<%= content_tag(:table, class: "table") do %>
…
Rows and cells etc
…
<% end %>
```

I want to output it as raw HTML for users to copy-and-paste. How do I do that?

Can I wrap the entire block in something like `<%= raw do %>…<% end %>`? (That obviously doesn't work BTW)

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2):

`CGI::escapeHTML` can do it. You should be able to call

```
<%= CGI.escapeHTML content_tag(:table, class: "table") do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

**Update, better way:**

The `h` method, of course!

```
<%=h content_tag(:table, class: "table") do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```